# Windows Phone 7. Как удалить PhoneApplicationPage из памяти

Tags: windows-phone-7

Как освободить память от неиспользуемой страницы(PhoneApplicationPage)?
В моей модели навигации некоторые страницы приходиться удалять из списка NavigationService. Но деструктор в этих страницах не вызывается - они просто продолжают занимать память.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще-то, как известно, сборщик мусора сам решает, когда освобождать память. Если у вас все правильно сделано и на страницу или ее элементы не ведет никаких ссылок, сборщик мусора через некоторое время освободит занимаемую ей память. Также стоит заметить, что если вы отслеживаете потребление памяти, запуская приложение под дебагом, то сама среда может держать ссылку на страницу, не давая сборщику собрать память. Профилирование стоит проводить только в режиме Release.

Конечно, можно [явно сказать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26757319/1985167) сборщику, чтобы он освобождал память после того как вы удаляете страницу из стэка навигации, но это очень нерекомендуемый способ делать дела.